# solr: Adding content-disposition to SolrQueryResponse

Tags: solr

I have a custom request handler that is extending RequestHandlerBase.

The purpose of this handler is to search the index for the given user query. Instead of omitting the results on the browser at client side, the response data should be downloaded as a file. Here is my handleRequestBody function code

```
@Override

public void handleRequestBody(final, SolrQueryRequest req,final SolrQueryResponse res) {
    tempFile = File.createTempFile(UUID.randomUUID().toString(),".tmp", new File(FILE_PATH));
    writeSearchResultstoFile(tempFile);
    ContentStreamBase outConentStream = new ContentStreamBase.FileStream(tempFile);
    outConentStream.setContentType("application/download");
    rsp.add(RawResponseWriter.CONTENT, outConentStream);
}
```

The problem is the file is being downloaded with .part file at client side.
rsp.getResponseHeader().add("Content-Disposition", "filename=data.csv");

didn't help much. Could some please tell me how to set the Content-Disposition.

Answer (score 1):

Since I see that you are formatting your results as CSV I am curious as to whether you have looked at the [CSVResponseFormat](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CSVResponseWriter) that Solr has supported since release 3.1

Comment: Yeah..I have looked at it.. But <br/> 1) I am using older version of solr that doesn't have CSVResponseWriter. <br/> 2) CSVResponse writer spits the result on the browser